# How to adjust color for Quick Mask in Gimp

Tags: gimp, mask

By default in Gimp, when I toggle quick mask, it gives me a red background, which I can then use the paint brush to paint over portions of my design, to then enable select.  I get it, and that works fine.

But in cases where the design does not stick out so well when the red mask is on...is there a way we can change that red to another color, so we can get a more acurate paint over our designs?

In my case, I have an image of a football player who has a black scarf around his neck, all in the front-ground.  The back ground is also as dark as his neck scarf.  I would like to change the red tone to something different so I can see his neck scarf better(i.e. where it starts and end).

[image]

Is this possible with Gimp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Well hidden in the preferences:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that find!  A Gimp restart is also needed.